# jquery siblings addclass and removeclass not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have element div more thank 20 inside li, the selected is base on iframe load, so if the iframe is load on the 20 div, sibling selected is not working on list_1. heres the example code.

```
<li>
<div id="list_1" class=""></div>
<div id="list_2" class=""></div>
<div id="list_3" class=""></div>
<div id="list_4" class=""></div>
<div id="list_5" class=""></div>
<div id="list_6" class=""></div>
<div id="list_7" class=""></div>
<div id="list_8" class=""></div>
<div id="list_9" class=""></div>
<div id="list_10" class=""></div>
<div id="list_11" class=""></div>
<div id="list_12" class=""></div>
<div id="list_13" class=""></div>
<div id="list_14" class=""></div>
<div id="list_15" class=""></div>
<div id="list_16" class=""></div>
<div id="list_17" class=""></div>
<div id="list_18" class=""></div>
<div id="list_19" class=""></div>
<div id="list_20" class="selected"></div>
</li>

var e = $('div[id^="list_20"]');
e.addClass('selected).siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: there's some mess there. var e gets populated with div having id starting with list_20 and you are adding a class "selected" but you didn't correctly close the quote on the selector. In general it seems the right strategy to remove first the "selected" class from any of those div and than add the class to the div#id you wish to highlight

Comment: You are missing a `'` in `e.addClass('selected)`

Comment: thank bro, i just change the selector into $('#list_1')